# Change list of dates into text

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I'm trying to convert list of dates into text. Here I'm going to give some examples:

1) List of dates (`dd/mm/yy`):

```
31/03/2016 
06/04/2016
13/04/2016
20/04/2016
27/04/2016
```

I want to change this list into text like: **Every Wednesday of Week from 03/31/2016 to 04/27/2016**

2) List of dates (`dd/mm/yy`):

```
01/01/2017
01/02/2017
01/01/2018
01/02/2018
01/01/2019
01/02/2019
01/01/2020
01/02/2020
```

I want to change this list into text like: 1**st day of 1st and 2nd month of each year from 01/01/2017 to 01/01/2020**

Please share any script or plugin in jquery to do this task.

Thanks

Comment: What type of list is this? Is this a csv-file or just plain text?
Or just single string-values?

Comment: Dates can get tricky pretty fast. I'd recommend using a library like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) which handles them really well.

Comment: @John You can assume that these dates are in array.

Comment: Is this Array chronologically sorted? Like example 1)

Comment: Yes, it will always be chronologically sorted

Comment: @AmitThukral look at my Answer below. this should provide what you need.

Answer (score 0):

So this is a nice function that provides you the output you need.
Just give the function 2 Arguments: `array` and `text`.
It will return the message, that you can store or print as needed.

```js
var arr1 = ["31/03/2016", "06/04/2016", "13/04/2016", "20/04/2016", "27/04/2016"];
var arr2 = ["01/01/2017", "01/02/2017", "01/01/2018", "01/02/2018", "01/01/2019", "01/02/2019", "01/01/2020", "01/02/2020"];
var infoText1 = "Every Wednesday of Week from ";
var infoText2 = "1st day of 1st and 2nd month of each year from ";

function showMessage(array, text) {
  var newArr = [];
  array.forEach(function(e, i) {
    tmpArr = array[i].split("/");
    tmpArr.unshift(tmpArr[1]);
    tmpArr.splice(2, 1);
    newArr.push(tmpArr.join("/"));
  })
  return text + newArr.shift() + " to " + newArr.pop();
}

var message = showMessage(arr1, infoText1) // <-- this is your output

document.write(message); // just to test the output
```

Comment: Hey @John, Thanks for your answer but I also want to make the week name or Days of months dynamic. Like in case of Wednesday, it can be another day (like Tuesday, Monday). or Days: (1, 2), it can be another days like (5, 6, 7, 8). Does it make sense?

Comment: But you can change the texts and arrays as you want.
You just give any text or array to the function and it will spit out
you desired pattern.

You can change infoText1 etc. as needed.